# Scala populate a case class for each list item

Tags: scala

I have a csv file of countries and a CountryData case class

Example data from file:

> Denmark, Europe, 1.23, 7.89
>
> Australia, Australia, 8.88, 9.99
>
> Brazil, South America, 7.77,3.33

```
case class CountryData(country: String, region: String, population: Double, economy: Double)
```

I can read in the file and split, etc to get

(List(Denmark, Europe, 1.23, 7.89)
(List(Australia, Australia, 8.88, 9.99)
(List(Brazil, South America, 7.77,3.33)

How can I now populate a CountryData case class for each list item?
I've tried:

```
for (line <- Source.getLines.drop(1)) {  
val splitInput = line.split(",", -1).map(_.trim).toList
val country = splitInput(0)
val region = splitInput(1)
val population = splitInput(2)
val economy = splitInput(3)

val dataList: List[CountryData]=List(CountryData(country,region,population,economy))
```

But that doesn't work because it's not reading the val, it sees it as a string 'country' or 'region'.

Comment: General advice: try to break down the problem and isolate the issue. For example, what's the value of `splitInput`? Why is it part of the question? Make sure you are reading and parsing the file correctly and then update your question by setting the `splitInput` to whatever value it holds and remove the file reading part. My guess is that somewhere in the first line of your CSV you have headers / column names and that's what you're reading. I can see that you want to drop it, but perhaps there's an empty line before that. Either way, case class populating should work as you expect it to.

Comment: `population` and `economy` need to be `Double`

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where exactly is your issue. Is it about `Double` vs `String` or about `List` being inside the loop. Still something like this will probably work

```
case class CountryData(country: String, region: String, population: Double, economy: Double)


object CountryDataMain extends App {
  val src = "\nDenmark, Europe, 1.23, 7.89\nAustralia, Australia, 8.88, 9.99\nBrazil, South America, 7.77,3.33"

  val list = Source.fromString(src).getLines.drop(1).map(line => {
    val splitInput = line.split(",", -1).map(_.trim).toList
    val country = splitInput(0)
    val region = splitInput(1)
    val population = splitInput(2)
    val economy = splitInput(3)

    CountryData(country, region, population.toDouble, economy.toDouble)
  }).toList

  println(list)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use scala case matching: i.e.

```
def doubleOrNone(str: Double): Option[Double] = {
   Try {
      Some(str.toDouble) //Not sure of exact name of method, should be quick to find
   } catch {
      case t: Throwable => None
  }
}    

def parseCountryLine(line: String): Vector[CountryData] = {
   lines.split(",").toVector match {
      case Vector(countryName, region, population, economy) => CountryData(countryName, region, doubleOrNone(population), doubleOrNone(economy))//I would suggest having them as options because you may not have data for all countries
      case s => println(s"Error parsing line:\n$s"); 
   }
}
```